# Is there a bug with Strunk & White badge or am I not understanding it?

Tags: support, badges

According to the description the [image] badge is awarded for editing 80 posts.  It only shows [4 users have earned this badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) but there are more including myself who have made over 80 edits and have not received the badge.

Comment: It is not always clear, but [it appears](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) edits to your own posts or edits that only change tags do not count. There is a Data Explorer query to [find out how much more edits you have to do to get the badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges), but you'll have to wait until the WordPress data is loaded there.

Comment: Thanks Jan.  Can't wait till our data is loaded thats a great tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make over 80 edits to other people's posts? Only body edits on other people's posts count toward the badge.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Most of my edits are tag and title.

Comment: The post [explaining the changes in February](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260) still talks about "title or body", so I think title edits also count? Multiple edits to the same post are only counted once, of course.