# Am I not understanding the "Unsung Hero" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I was at first hesitant to ask this question, but I did see a related (yet much older) one here in meta: [Is there a bug with Strunk & White badge or am I not understanding it?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/551/is-there-a-bug-with-strunk-white-badge-or-am-i-not-understanding-it).  However, if I turn out to be wrong and this is incorrect or lame, I'm not above deleting this question.

I earned the "Tenacious" badge.  I believe that I have enough zero score answers to have also earned the "Unsung Hero" badge, but that one is not showing.  I thought it may be that there's a time period (waiting to see if someone votes or changes the accepted answer, etc), but that doesn't seem to be the case.  So just trying to understand why.

I have 27 accepted answers, 12 are zero score answers.  That's more than 10 and 25% of the total.

Is the calculation inclusive of **all** answers (including non-accepted answers)?  If so, I have 64 total answers (including not-accepted answers). Could that be it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirements of the [Unsung Hero Badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) is as follows:

- More than 10 of your answers are zero score accepted answers
- AND Must be 25% of your total answers

So of all the answers you've posted, 25% of them need to both be accepted and have a score of 0. The 10 limit prevents new users from prematurely getting the badge.

You have a total of 64 answers, 12 of which are accepted and have a score of 0. That means that 18.75% of your answers are 0 score accepted answers which doesn't quite meet the requirement but is close.

Comment: Ahhh... I was looking at it as the zero score answers as 25% of accepted answers.  But it makes sense now.  Thanks!